# ¿Hasta cuando Apple dará soporte a Objective C?

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Tengo unas aplicaciones construidas con Objective C, y migrarlas a swift no es una opción. Alguien sabe ¿Hasta cuando Apple dará soporte a Objective C?
gracias.

Comment: Esta no es una pregunta que pueda ser respondida en un sitio de programación. Intenta preguntar en [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo. Es una pregunta concisa que puede ser respondida y es sobre desarrollo de aplicaciones.

Comment: @kerunaru mira el centro de ayuda. yo tampoco considero propia.

Comment: @lois6b creo que esta pregunta entra perfectamente en la categoría de "herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores", por lo tanto, la veo totalmente apropiada.

Comment: @kerunaru. No. Una pregunta de ese tipo seria sobre el funcionamiento de xcode en el tema de programación. No sobre una pregunta que deberia formular a Apple si es que no hay un articulo de ellos al respecto

Comment: @lois6b creo entonces que habría que definir qué se considera herramienta de software. Objective-C también es una herramienta de software aunque no sea del mismo tipo que Xcode.

Comment: @kerunaru como sea. la comunidad ha votado y se ha cerrado. Eres bienvenido a abrir una pregunta en meta al respecto pidiendo mas votaciones o preguntando qué consideran "herramientas de software"

Comment: @lois6b [hecho](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1331/a-qu%C3%A9-nos-referimos-con-herramientas-de-softwre-en-el-centro-de-ayuda)

Comment: @kerunaru perfecto :D

Answer (score 2):

Apple no se ha pronunciado al respecto. En su [guía](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-ID0) lo que sí que dice es:

> we can now introduce a new language for the future of Apple software development.

Cabe esperar que en algún momento dejen de darle soporte. Si te planteas nuevos proyectos, hazlos en swift directamente.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo. Creo que empezar algo ahora con ObjC es ir para atrás

Comment: Concuerdo con ello también, todo desarrollo nuevo se debería de hacer don Swift, pero tengo la duda, sobre las aplicaciones que están con Objc, será que es necesario migrarlas en un futuro a Swift?

Comment: No entiendo el voto negativo. Una cosa es que, al parecer, la pregunta no sea relevante y otra es que mi respuesta no sea correcta xD

Comment: @kerunaru te recomiendo agregar la fuente de la información.

Comment: @Mauricio, hecho